# How to capture all input text and output in bash when executing a file in script?

Tags: bash

I want to execute a cpp file (say a.out) and store the output to a variable in a bash script. a.out is like the following:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter a Value:
```

It will prompt a message for user input. After typing in:

```
Enter a Value: 10
You entered 10
```

When I try to do the following in a bash script:

```
output="$(./a.out)"
echo "$output"
```

The prompt message is gone but it is still waiting for input, and I get the output like this:

```
10
Enter a Value: You entered 10
```

Is there any way that I can get totally same behavior on the screen as directly execting a.out file in the command line and still store the output from the program in a bash script?
In other words, I still need the prompt message to be on the screen when running the bash script.

Thanks.

Comment: You can write the prompt to stderr (or the tty) instead of stdout. That way it won't be captured as part of the program output. If the program insists on writing all output to the same place, you'll have to awkwardly try to separate them after the fact.

Comment: I may not be clear. So I still want the prompt message from other programs showing up on the screen to users.

Comment: You can use `output=$(./a.out | tee /dev/stderr)` to show output both on screen and capture it. However, if you only want to show the prompt on screen while capturing the rest, you need to do the above. For example, in a C++ program you can replace `std::cout << "Enter a value: "` with `std::cerr << "Enter a value: "`.

Comment: It works. So here is my understanding of your solution. "tee" copies the prompt and the output from stdout to the stderr so that both of them can show up on screen. Is it correct? How about I also want to keep the input in $output? which means $output="Enter a Value: 10\nYou entered 10".

Comment: You can't. If what you're really looking for is a transcript of a user's interaction with a program, try the tool `script`